# How to run Symfony2 console commands inside NetBeans?

Tags: symfony

I have created a symfony 2 project. Now I do not able set up Symfony2 in windows using netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Symfony plugin in Netbeans, if you have not do this.
Then click right button on project title and you'll see "Symfony2" in context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one will help you, it worked for me...

http://software-talk.org/blog/2012/06/symfony2-tutorial-netbeans-and-symfony2-setting-everything-up/